# How to extract reCAPTCHAV3 URL from the network's tab

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha-v3

```
`#From use of xpath
from pypasser import reCaptchaV3
import requests
from lxml import html
import time
#import ffmpeg

def mail_checker3(email):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"}
        
    with requests.Session() as s:
        url1 = "https://alphamenslab.co.nz/account/login#recover"
        response1 = s.get(url1, headers=headers)
        print(response1.status_code)
        tree1 = html.fromstring(response1.content)
        time.sleep(60)

        #Extract dynamic values xpaths and reCAPTCHA token's url from network tab
        reCaptcha_response = reCaptchaV3(
            #"https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LcCR2cUAAAAANS1Gpq_mDIJ2pQuJphsSQaUEuc9&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYW1lbnNsYWIuY28ubno6NDQz&hl=en&v=3kTz7WGoZLQTivI-amNftGZO&size=invisible&cb=tcptijhnklqd"
        )

        # Set the data for the POST request (payload)
        data = {
            "form_type": "recover_customer_password",
            "utf8": "✓",
            "recaptcha-v3-token": reCaptcha_response,
            "email": email,   
        }

        # Now send the POST request.
        url2 = "https://alphamenslab.co.nz/account/recover"
        response2 = s.post(url2, data=data, headers=headers)
        print(response2.status_code)
        #print(response2.history)
        #print(response2.content)
        #exit()

        # Parse the response using lxml
        tree2 = html.fromstring(response2.content)
        
        result = tree2.xpath('//*[@id="RecoverEmail-email-error"]')[0].get("value")
        if (result == "No account found with that email. "):
            return ("No user found.")
        else:
            return ("User exists.")
        
email = "test@gmail.com"
ans = mail_checker3(email)
print(ans)
`
```

Now when I run this program the first status code comes out to be 200 but the status code for response2 comes to be 429, but the content is getting printed. I have done scraping questions. But I am having problem with this variety. Mainly I want to learn how to extract the recpatca url from the networks tab. Cause there are multiple URLs looking similar. But please try to resolve this using only requests module only not regex and beautifulsoup.